# Swift NSString to String on Linux

Tags: swift

In docs I found article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

And a code:

```
import Foundation
let myString: NSString = "123"
if let integerValue = Int(myString as String) {
    print("\(myString) is the integer \(integerValue)")
}
// prints "123 is the integer 123"
```

On MacOS it worked, but in Lunux didn't.
I got an error:

> error: cannot convert value of type 'NSString' to type 'String' in
>   coercion if let integerValue = Int(myString as String) {

Comment: I have never tried Swift on linux, so I can't speak how to that even works, but are you possibly using an older Swift (<2.0) version on your linux setup?

Comment: I tried on mac with swift 2.2 and Linux with swift 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the Linux compiler… I would suggest the following workarounds.

```
let myString: NSString = "123"
if let integerValue = Int(String(myString)) {
    print("\(myString) is the integer \(integerValue)")
}
```

or

```
let myString: NSString = "123"
if myString.isEqualToString("0") || myString.integerValue != 0 {
    print("\(myString) is the integer \(myString.integerValue)")
}
```

Comment: You can test here: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dWdevcenter-_-swift-_-lp&cm_mc_uid=11602763416914412976120&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1451194962#/repl

Comment: Nope! `NSString` is hopelessly broken in this implementation. `myString.description` returns the wrong result and `myString.integerValue` produces an unknown error in the output.